# Defining a function in Sage

Tags: sagemath

How do I define the following function in Sage and compute some values?

The function is $$P(n) = \sqrt{\frac{e^{-h}h^n}{n!}},$$

where $h$ is a real variable and $n$ is a nonnegative integer. I want to see the values of $P(n)$ for $h = 20$ from $n = 0$ to $n = 50$.

After this, I would like to use the function in other formulas such as $$A(n,t) = P(n)\cos(t\sqrt(n+1))\cos(\theta) - iP(n+1)$$

So, if you help me out with computing $P(n),$ I think I will be able to do the rest.
Thank you!

Comment: I think I just did it. All I needed to do was print in the command box the following code: "P(n) = sqrt(((exp(-h))*h^n)/(factorial(n)))"

Comment: For questions about Sage syntax, the Q&A site http://ask.sagemath.org is usually a better choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sage: var('h')
h
sage: P(n) = sqrt(e^-h * h^n/factorial(n))
sage: points((n,P(n).subs(h=20)) for n in [0..50])
```

[image]